# import theano, something wrong about the driver, raise Exception()

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, theano-cuda

My OS is Win10_64, i've installed cuda8.0, and i already have the graphics driver updated

but..
when i type in 'import theano', it says:

```
DEBUG: nvcc STDOUT mod.cu
building library: C:/Users/asus/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-
Intel64_Family_6_Model_60_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.6.0-64/tmp81safx1e/m91973e5c136ea49268a916ff971b7377.lib and subject C:/Users/asus/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_60_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.6.0-64/tmp81safx1e/
m91973e5c136ea49268a916ff971b7377.exp

Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX 960M (CNMeM is enabled with initial size: 80.0% of memory, 
cuDNN 5005)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "mlp.py", line 10, in <module>
     import theano
   File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py", 
       line 111, in <module>
     theano.sandbox.cuda.tests.test_driver.test_nvidia_driver1()
   File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox
      \cuda\tests\test_driver.py", line 39, in test_nvidia_driver1

     raise Exception("The nvidia driver version installed with this OS "
Exception: The nvidia driver version installed with this OS does not give good results for 
reduction.Installing the nvidia driver available on the same download page as the cuda package 
will fix the problem: http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads
```

---

and
My python version is 3.6
I don't know if it's about the version of cuda or something else?

When i type in nvcc -V, it shows:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Jan__9_17:32:33_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.60
```

So i guess cuda is ok.

don't know how to solve it...

I'll appreciate if you know how to solve it.
Thank you!

Comment: hi~I also meet this problem, my driver version is 376.51, cuda8.0. Do you slove it ??

Comment: Ahh,,I just saw this...sorry~~~~~~~
I don't use theano anymore, instead I use tensorflow,, so I just left the problem...
I didn't solve it. Sorry about it!